# Is a transit visa required for South Africa?

Tags: visas, transit

I am travelling from Wenzhou, China to Windhoek, Namibia. I have a self-transfer ticket. I have two stops WNZ>HKG>JNB>WDH. Do I need a transit visa in JNB?

Comment: You don't mention your citizenship, which is the most important... Although, from your writing style I'd wager the Indian subcontinent.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am Namibian.

Answer (score 3):

Savera, as a Nambian, you are visa free in South Africa for up to 90 days. You don't need a transit visa.